# In android how to get selected image in listview?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have listview with image and text. Image and text are coming from sqlite. I got the selected item text. But  till now i cannot get the selected image. how can i get the selected image and how to pass that image to next activity? can anyone help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use [AdapterView.OnItemClickListerner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html), you will be notified when the list item is clicked. In the callback method, you will be provided some parameter which can help you determine the data of selected item.

In some case, If you want to handle the click event by your self with [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html), you have to enable focus-able and clickable abilities of list-item inside the Adapter#getView() method. Then, you just anchor the bitmap to list-item by call View#setTag().

Hope this helps.